# PostgreSQL C functions not resolved by Eclipse CPP

Tags: sql, c, eclipse, postgresql

I am trying to write a C function to be executed within PostgreSQL, something that will be declared like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...
RETURNS ... AS 'my_c_function' LANGUAGE C;
```

I followed the documentation and wrote a code containing stuff like `PGFUNCTION_INFO_V1(func);` or `PG_GETARG_VARCHAR(0);`. The problem is Eclipse keeps telling me these cannot be resolved. Here are the libraries I included:

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <postgres.h>
#include <fmgr.h>
#include <funcapi.h>
#include <executor/executor.h>

#include <string.h>
```

Should I include something else ? What am I missing ?

Comment: That's normal (on Linux). They will be resolved at run time. You have to build as a shared library, not as an executable. I don't know Eclipse as C environment, so I can't help with the details.

Comment: Including headerfiles does not use the library itself; did you specify the library libpq at the linker command line?

Answer (score 0):

Your index may be out of date. Try rebuilding your index from the project menu.

`Project > C/C++ Index > Rebuild`

Additionally, make sure your included path is specified in your project settings if there is an issue including `<postgres.h>`.